# C++ Generate a random prime using GMP library

Tags: c++, random, primes, gmp

I was looking into [GMP documentation](https://gmplib.org/gmp-man-6.1.2.pdf). I couldn't find any function for generating random prime of a given length. One simple way to do it is:

```
while true
{
     mpz_urandomb(sampled_value, random_state, length);
     if (!mpz_probab_prime_p(sampled_value, 50))
          break;
}
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient GMP library function to sample random prime of a given length. I would like to sample many random primes. Is there a function that does this more efficiently than sampling each of them in a loop.

Comment: @Aakash Thoriya I tried using random_ndgit_prime function. It is not present in GMP library. So, removing the edit you mentioned.

Comment: @AakashThoriya most importantly, if you think you have a solution post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question!

Comment: @Aakash Thoriya The link that you posted is for PERL language.

Comment: No, that is the most efficient method of generating random primes.

Comment: How about `mpz_nextprime()`?  Pick a random number in the range you want and find the next prime?